# memoize using the `function f();` syntax

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I can memoize a function with:

- `const f = memoize(function(){/* ... */})`
- `const f = memoize(() => {/* ... */})`

However, for the purpose of generating nice docs, I need to use the syntax:

```
function f() {
  /* ... */
}
```

How can I memoize that?

Comment: `function f()` can't be used to define functions dynamically, it can only be followed by a literal body.

Answer (score 4):

just append the line:

```
 function f() {
   /* ... */
 }
 // @ts-ignore
 f = memoize(f);
```

Comment: `[ts] Cannot assign to 'f' because it is not a variable.`

Comment: @amaurymartiny You didn't mention you're using typescript

Comment: Right, sorry about that. Added.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Jonas said, you can simply overwrite the declared variable afterwards (`f = memoise(f)`). A modern alternative would be to use the [proposed and experimental *decorators*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) together with your favourite transpiler, and write

```
@memoise
function f() {
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Would be a syntax I am looking for. However, tc39 doesn't address decorators for functions. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/issues/40

Comment: @amaurymartiny Oh dammit, you're of course right. I suppose decorators used in Typescript have the same limitation?

Answer (score 1):

Do the `const f1 = memoize(function(){/* ... */})` or `const f1 = memoize(() => {/* ... */})` as you prefer, and then write `function f() { ... }` that just calls `f1` with its parameters and returns the result.

Comment: In my docs, I would then have the function definition of `f1`.

Comment: I don't understand.  If this is the typical JSDoc kind of thing and you put the documentation comment on `f`, then `f` should appear in your documentation.  Or what tool are you using?

Comment: Typedoc, and they don't document prettily `const f = ...` syntax. If I put doc comments on `f1`, then `f1` shows in the docs. Though getting kind of off-topic.

Comment: Might you have read the answer backwards?  I suggested to use `const f1 = ...` and then `function f() { ... }`.

Comment: Ah right, you're totally correct, my bad! Upvoted your answer, though I still prefer @Jonas's.